# Highlight 4 consecutive matching word

Tags: php

I have two strings one is modal answer & other is answer given by student. I want to highlight 4 consecutive matching words with modal answer from answer given by student.

I have written below function to match & highlight words from answer string.

```
function getCopiedText($modelAnswer, $answer) {
    $modelAnsArr = explode(' ', $modelAnswer);
    $answerArr = explode(' ', $answer);
    $common = array_intersect($answerArr, $modelAnsArr);
    if (isset($common) && !empty($common)) {
        $common[max(array_keys($common)) + 2] = '';
        $count = 0;
        $word = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i <= max(array_keys($common)); $i++) {
            if (isset($common[$i])) {
                $count++;
                $word .= $common[$i] . ' ';
            } else {
                if ($count >= 4) {
                    $answer = preg_replace("@($word)@i", '<span style="color:blue">$1</span>', $answer);
                }
                $count = 0;
                $word = '';
            }
        }
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

**sample strings**

```
$modelAnswer = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';

$answer ='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
```

**function call**

```
echo getCopiedText($modelAnswer, $answer);
```

**Issue**:
When `$answer` string is more than 300 characters above function will not return highlighted string. If suppose `$answer` string is less than 300 characters then it will return the highlighted string. e.g. suppose `$answer` string is `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.` it return the highlighted string. But not for characters having more than 300.

I am not sure but it seems like there is issue with `preg_replace` function. Maybe pattern(first param of `preg_replace`) length goes beyond limit.

Comment: Did you notice that the `else` within `for` never runs? Currently it outputs `$answer` as is.

Comment: it runs. Try with less than 300 chars in `$answer` e.g. `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`

Comment: Check it here https://3v4l.org/iV5IO

Comment: please enter first sentence from model answer for `$answer`

Comment: @revo I found the solution but there is another issue if string contains special characters ? ( @ then is also fails

Comment: What is the desired result? Are you wanting to highlight the entire answer if 4 consecutive words match, or highlight each set of matching consecutive 4 words? Additionally are you wanting to exclude the special characters from the `$answer` outright, or only consider them if they are in the model? I also notice you used `@i` in your regex, but `array_intersect` is case-sensitive. Are you wanting the words from the answer and model to match regardless of case?

Comment: @fyrye just wanted to highlight 4 consecutive words match not entire answer only matching sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding a separate answer, since the OP commented afterward that they really desire to match phrases of 4 or more words. And my original answer was based on the comment by the OP initially desiring to match sets of 4 word phrases.

I refactored the original answer to use the [`CachingIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php) to iterate over every word instead of sets of only 4 words. As well as the ability to specify the minimum number of words in each phrase (default 4), handling of shortened duplicate phrases and rewind when encountering a partial match.

Example:

```
Model: "one two three four one two three four five six seven"
Answer:
    "two three four five two three four five six seven"
Shortened Duplicate:: 
    "[two three four five] [[two three four five] six seven]"

Answer: 
    "one one two three four"
Partial Match Rewind:
    "one [one two three four]"
```

*Source https://3v4l.org/AKRTQ*

---

### Example: https://3v4l.org/5P2L6

> This solution is case-insensitive and considers both special `@ (, )` and non-printable
>   characters `\n\r\t`.
>
> I recommend removing all non-alphanumeric characters from both the
>   answer and model, to sanitize them for comparison and make the
>   detection algorithm more predictable.
>
> `preg_replace(['/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u', '/[[:space:]]{2,}/u'], ['', ' '], $answer);` https://3v4l.org/Pn6CT
>
> Alternatively instead of using `explode` you could use `str_word_count($answer, 1, '1234567890')` https://3v4l.org/cChjo Which will accomplish the same results, while retaining hyphenated and apostrophized words.

```
function getCopiedText($model, $answer, $min = 4)
{
    //ensure there are not double spaces
    $model = str_replace('  ', ' ', $model);
    $answer = str_replace('  ', ' ', $answer);
    $test = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator(explode(' ', $answer)));
    $words = $matches = [];
    $p = $match = null;
    //test each word
    foreach($test as $i => $word) {
        $words[] = $word;
        $count = count($words);
        if ($count === 2) {
            //save pointer at second word
            $p = $i;
        }
        //check if the phrase of words exists in the model
        if (false !== stripos($model, $phrase = implode(' ', $words))) {
            //only match phrases with the minimum or more words
            if ($count >= $min) {
                //reset back to here for more matches
                $match = $phrase;
                if (!$test->hasNext()) {
                    //add the the last word to the phrase
                    $matches[$match] = true;
                    $p = null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            //the phrase of words was no longer found
            if (null !== $match && !isset($matches[$match])) {
                //add the matched phrase to the list of matches
                $matches[$match] = true;
                $p = null;
                $iterator = $test->getInnerIterator();
                if ($iterator->valid()) {
                    //rewind pointer back to the current word since the current word may be part of the next phrase
                    $iterator->seek($i);
                }
            } elseif (null !== $p) {
                //match not found, determine if we need to rewind the pointer
                $iterator = $test->getInnerIterator();
                if ($iterator->valid()) {
                    //rewind pointer back to second word since a partial phrase less than 4 words was matched
                    $iterator->seek($p);
                }
                $p = null;
            }
            //reset testing
            $words = [];
            $match = null;
        }
    }

    //highlight the matched phrases in the answer
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $phrases = array_keys($matches);
        //sort phrases by the length
        array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $phrases), $phrases);

        //filter the matches as regular expression patterns
        //order by longest phrase first to ensure double highlighting of smaller phrases
        $phrases  = array_map(function($phrase) {
            return '/(' . preg_quote($phrase, '/') . ')/iu';
        }, array_reverse($phrases));

        $answer = preg_replace($phrases, '<span style="color:blue">$0</span>', $answer);
    }

    return $answer;
}
```

```
$modelAnswer = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';

$answer ='NOT IN is simply dummy text NOT in when an unknown printer took a galley -this- is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry';

echo getCopiedText($modelAnswer, $answer);
```

Results:

```html
NOT IN <span style="color:blue">is simply dummy text</span> NOT in <span style="color:blue">when an unknown printer took a galley</span> -this- <span style="color:blue"><span style="color:blue">is simply dummy text</span> of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
```

Comment: I am using zend framework, how can we use php CachingIterator in zend.

Comment: @Omi [`CachingIterator`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php) and [`ArrayIterator`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) are default php SPL iterators available in PHP 5+, if you're using it within a namespace, prefix them both with the global namespace ie `\CachingIterator()`

Comment: thanks its working now. I will get back to you on answer.

Comment: it does not match words separated by new line. e.g. when 6 char in one line, 4 on second line & 3 on third line. e.g. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer(\n) 
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo(\n) 
ligula eget dolor.

Comment: @Omi This was commented on in the quotes, the non-printable characters `\r`, `\n`, in the `$answer` have to match the exact placement (verbatim) within the `$model`. i.e. if answer has `\r\n` and model does not or only has `\n`, no match will occur either https://3v4l.org/Pi5Hi As you can see the first 2 answers with line-breaks match the phrases, while the others do not. To circumvent the issue, sanitize the model and answer values. Otherwise you would need to split the model and answer into separate instances from the line-breaks.

Comment: will it fix the issue by sanitizing `$model` only? we can sanitize `$answer` but need to return answer in same formatting

Comment: Sadly no, as PHP will treat `one\ntwo`, `one\n` or `\ntwo` as one word in the answer, that does not exist in the model and vice versa. Without knowing where the `\n` matches in the answer compared to the model, there's no reasonable way to determine what phrase to highlight in the answer.

Comment: @Omi The only alternative would be to do `$answers = explode("\n", $answer);`  then do `foreach($answers as $answer) { $validatedAnswers[] = getCopiedText($modelAnswer, $answer); }` then combine them all back using `$answer = implode("\n", $validatedAnswers);` But you would lose context of the previous answer (for example last answer only contains 3 words). So you would need a means to continue the last matched phrase to the next answer using recursion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187906/discussion-between-fyrye-and-omi).

Comment: Hey @fyrye, one issue is found, suppose question is text `Write a message to Jane. Invite her` and answer text is `A message to Jane. I invite her`. What happening I is getting highlighted cause it match with I from word invite.(`Write a message to Jane. I`nvite her). I should not highlight in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: @Omi It's possible, but would require a 1 to 1 comparison of each word at the positions in the model matching the answer words. I suggest asking a separate question to see if someone can provide more insight than myself.

Comment: I have changed some code. Here is new updated code https://3v4l.org/3pBFR. It should highlight last paragraph from $answer but due to new line it is not highlighting. Could you please help. New question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076253/

Comment: I have some new enhancement. I need to ignore the punctuation mark from word and match. here is new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987597

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not entirely sure of your desired end results. It appears that you are attempting to highlight any set of 4 consecutive words in the the given answer, that are matched consecutively in the model. As to determine occurrences of potential plagiarism.

Based on your comment about retrieving matched sets of 4 words, there are quite a few optimizations I would like to suggest.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/uvPug

```
function getCopiedText($model, $answer) 
{
    $test = explode(' ', $answer);
    while ($test) {
        if (count($test) < 4) {
            break;
        }
        //retrieve 4 consecutive words from the answer and remove them
        $words = array_splice($test, 0, 4);
        $phrase = implode(' ', $words);
        //ensure the phrase is found in the model
        if (false !== stripos($model, $phrase)) {
            $answer = str_ireplace($phrase, '<span style="color:blue">' . $phrase . '</span>', $answer);
        }
    }

    return $answer;
}

$modelAnswer = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';

$answer ='NOT IN is simply dummy text NOT IN when an unknown printer took a galley -this- is simply dummy text';

echo getCopiedText($modelAnswer, $answer);
```

Results:

```
NOT IN <span style="color:blue">is simply dummy text</span> NOT IN <span style="color:blue">when an unknown printer</span> took a galley -this- <span style="color:blue">is simply dummy text</span>
```

---

Tip for your original approach.

Whenever passing a variable to a `regex` function in PHP, you need to ensure it has been escaped appropriately using [`preg_quote`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). This will ensure special characters in the variable, such as `@` and `\n` or `\\`, are considered as part of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you!!. It works like a charm. But there are some limitations if model string contains new lines , it does not match. E.g. suppose we have less than 4 characters in first line,same on second line then nothing will be highlighted.

Comment: @Omi correct, as that would be considered a non-printable character. Since PHP is able to compare strings with non-printable characters, they would break any consecutive word matching against the model, (ie verbatim copying). There are a few approaches to circumvent the issue with non-printable characters, the easiest would be to simply remove them from the answer and model for comparison, as a form of sanitization.

Comment: yea that make sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is one issue, if there are 3 words remains at last it does not highlight if previous words are highlighted. So it would be like 4 or more consecutive word should highlight.

Comment: @Omi added a second answer as the requirement changed, I have another alternative testing approach as well, which will iterate over every possible combination of words, but is much more cpu intensive.