# Compare two strings ignoring white spaces, new lines, breaks

Tags: php

I want to compare two string & highlight matching continuous 4 or more words.

I am getting problem when there is double space or new line in string, string is not highlighting.

E.g.
Suppose string1 is `Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, 
graphic or web designs.`

String2 is `laying out print, graphic`

Expected Output:

```
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in <span style="color:red">laying out print, 

graphic</span> or web designs.
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$str1 ="Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, 
graphic or web designs.";

$str2 = "/laying out print, graphic/iu";

echo preg_replace($str2, '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $str1);
?>
```

Note: String1 formatting should be same.

Here is complete code : https://3v4l.org/3pBFR
In this example it should highlight last paragraph from `$answer` but it is not highlighting.

Comment: Is always string2 to be searched in string1 or could be the opposite too?

Comment: not all time, but it is failing in case of new line, double space in string1 @Valentino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to replace any whitespace in `$str2` with `\s+`, which will then match any sequence of whitespace in `$str`. That can then be used in preg_replace as you are currently doing:

```
$str1 ="Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, 
graphic or web designs.";

$str2 = "laying   out
print, graphic";

$regex = preg_replace('/\s+/', '\s+', $str2);

echo preg_replace("/$regex/iu", '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $str1);
```

Output:

```html
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in <span style="color:red">laying out print,
graphic</span> or web designs.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EVIDX)

Note (as pointed out in the comments), it is safest to use [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on the replacement string, to allow for the case where it may contain regex special characters, or possibly the delimiter used in the final `preg_replace`. For example:

```php
$str1 ="Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, 
<i>graphic</i> or web designs.";

$str2 = "laying   out
print, <i>graphic</i>";

$regex = preg_replace('/\s+/', '\s+', preg_quote($str2, '/'));

echo preg_replace("/$regex/iu", '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $str1);
```

Without the `preg_quote`, the second `preg_replace` will fail with an "unknown modifier '>'" error.

Output:

```html
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in <span style="color:red">laying out print, 
<i>graphic</i></span> or web designs.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/C2IZT)

Comment: Here is my example https://3v4l.org/3pBFR. It should highlight last paragraph of $answer but due to new line it is not highlighting.

Comment: Ah... that is a different (and much more complicated) problem to the one you asked...

Comment: thats why i made simple and asked simple question, but now i dont understand where i should put your code.

Comment: @Omi my code won't work for your problem. You should add your demo link to the question so that others can see the true complexity of what you're asking.

Comment: @Omi actually I think I might take that back.Changing `return '/(' . preg_quote($phrase, '/') . ')/iu';` to `return preg_replace('/\s+/', '\s+', '/(' . preg_quote($phrase, '/') . ')/iu');` seems like it works. https://3v4l.org/TmflT

Comment: OMG, its working. how? could you please explain. Will it work if there is more than one space.

Comment: @Omi it should do. Initially I hadn't figured out exactly how your code worked (it's pretty cool btw) but on taking a longer look I do think my solution will fit into it.

Comment: @Omi no worries. You did all the hard work in generating the matching phrases, all I did was help put the finishing touches on it.

Comment: actually all hardwork did by @fyrye not me. Here is previous question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435397

Comment: thank you,he deserve that. but it is bad we cant mention him here in comment (@)

Comment: Thanks @Nick and @Omi I was unaware of the `preg_replace('/\s+/', '\s+')` trick, nice work!

Comment: Hey Nick and @fyrye, I need another enhancement could you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987597/ignore-the-punctuation-and-highlight-the-pattern-in-given-string

Comment: @Nick please bake `preg_quote()` into this answer so that I don't need to post a separate answer.  https://3v4l.org/Frt0F  Now using this page to close https://stackoverflow.com/q/71490113/2943403.

Comment: @mickmackusa good point, done.