# Ignore the punctuation and highlight the pattern in given string

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have one model string and list of matching patterns. I want to highlight all the matching pattern in given model string even if any words in pattern/model contains punctuation mark.

**Sample String:**

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`

**Pattern List:**

 `1. printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum
 2. industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
 3. type specimen book, It has survived
 4. but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
 5. containing Lorem Ipsum passages and
 6. PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`

**Expected Output:**
[image: expectedoutput]

**What I am getting output:**
[image]

**Problem:**

Here 1,3,5 pattern is not get highlighted. Because they contains some kind of punctuation mark but punctuation mark is not present in model for that word.

#1: In first pattern there is no punctuation mark after word `industry` rather model string have in `industry.`. It seems both words are different so this is not highlighting. But I want it should ignore the punctuation mark and highlight string.

#3: In third pattern, word has different punctuation `book,` and `book.`

**I want** to highlight the string even if there is any word having punctuation mark present in model or pattern string.(It would be fine if not highlight punctuation mark but it should highlight word)

**I don`t want any change in model string it should be same as it with punctuation just highlight matching pattern.**

```
<?php
$model = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
$phrases= [
    "printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum"
    , "industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,"
    ,"type specimen book, It has survived"
    ,"but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
    ,"containing Lorem Ipsum passages and"
    ,"PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
];

$phrases = array_map(function($phrase) {
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '\s+', '/(' . preg_quote($phrase, '/') . ')/iu');
}, array_reverse($phrases));

echo  $model = preg_replace($phrases, '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $model);
```

**Working example** :

https://3v4l.org/QD8WY

Comment: why not just strip the sample sentence of full stops and commas using preg_replace in the step before you match for the phrases?

Comment: Does `preg_replace('/[.,!]/', '', $model)` do it? https://3v4l.org/2pSZe ... or you want the punctuation included in the return?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes all the punctuation marks(these are enough .?!,:;-{}[]()'`"). I have already handled line endings now space and line endings are not important

Comment: @user3783243 exaclty it should be included in return. Model string should be same as it. Your solution is correct but it is missing punctuation from model string

Comment: @HaydenEastwood yes agreed but final string should have it dont want to loose punctuation from model string, then how can we add punctuation at the end in output string.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes I have tried but I dont have that much understanding of regular expression so getting problems. I have tried to replace all the punctuation mark from model and pattern string using `str_replace(array('?', '.',','), '', $model)` but I didn't understand how could I retain the punctuation mark in model string after highlighting text. Could you please give any advise?

Comment: A possibility is to use preg_match_all() to get all the positions of the punctuation you remove, and then add that punctuation in after the match and replace for highlights have been made. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @HaydenEastwood it sounds really good. Thank you

Comment: @HaydenEastwood I have tried preg_match_all but actually when we highlight string we add additional span for color due to that punctuation original position got changed. Any other way?

Comment: yes but since you know the size of the string you are inserting, you can offset the insert locations by the equivalent amount, so it should still work. So if the original position of a full stop is at 4, and you add a "<span style=' '>" statement, the new position of the full stop will be at 4 + the length of the new string. It's a bit cumbersome,  admittedly, but it should work.

Comment: i tried but it is getting difficult to get the insert location @HaydenEastwood, could you please help with some code

Comment: @HaydenEastwood suppose I have model string `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text` and modified string is `Lorem Ipsum is <span style="color:red">simply dummy text`. How can I find if `is simply` from model string contain `<span style="color:red">` in modified string

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your existing code to ignore punctuation differences between the model text and the phrases. Instead of just looking for matching spaces, you need to look for punctuation and spaces, and match each of them against punctuation and/or a space. This code should do what you want:

```
$phrases= [
    "printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum"
    , "industry`s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,"
    ,"type specimen book, It has survived"
    ,"but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
    ,"containing Lorem Ipsum passages and"
    ,"PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
];
$phrases = array_map(function($phrase) {
    return preg_replace(array('/[.?!,:;\-{}\[\]()\'`"]/', '/\s+/'), 
                        array('([.?!,:;\\-{}\\[\\]()\'`"]|\s+)', '([.?!,:;\\-{}\\[\\]()\'`"]*\s+|\s+[.?!,:;\\-{}\\[\\]()\'`"]*)'), 
                        "@$phrase@iu");
}, array_reverse($phrases));

echo  $model = preg_replace($phrases, '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $model);
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the <span style="color:red">printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the <span style="color:red">industry`s standard dummy text ever since
the 1500s,</span> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
<span style="color:red">type specimen book. It has survived</span> not only five centuries,
<span style="color:red">but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</span>
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets <span style="color:red">
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and</span> more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
<span style="color:red">PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ep7aZ)

Comment: @Omi did this help? If not, can you provide some more info to solve the problem? Or had you already solved it? If so, you should post your solution and accept that as an answer.